# Django South load fixtures based on environment (development, integration, production)

Tags: django, production-environment, fixtures, django-south

I'm working on a project that is using Django and South for migrations. I would like to set up some fixtures that would be used to populate the database in some environments (development, demo) but not in others (production). For example, I would like there to be some data in the system so the UI developer has something to work with in the interface they are working on or so we can quickly do a demo for a project manager without having to manually set things up via the admin interface.

While I have found plenty of ways to separate automated testing fixtures from regular fixtures, I have not been able to find anything about loading fixtures based on environment. Is this possible, or is there another way people solve this problem I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much you can do about `initial_data` fixtures. However, I've always felt those has less than optimal utility anyways. Rarely do you want the same fixture applied again and again with every call to `syncdb` or `migrate`.

If you're using some differently named fixture, you can easily cause it to run with your migration by adding the following to your forwards migration (from the [South docs](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/fixtures.html#fixtures-from-migrations))

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command("loaddata", "my_fixture.json")
```

So really, all you need is some way to only do that in certain environments. For dev, the easiest path would be to simply rely on `DEBUG`. So, the previous code becomes:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management import call_command
if settings.DEBUG:
    call_command("loaddata", "dev_fixture.json")
```

If you need greater control, you can create some sort of setting that will be different in each `local_settings.py` (or whatever methodology you use to customize settings based on environment). For example:

```
# local_settings.py
ENV = 'staging'

# migration
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management import call_command
if settings.ENV == 'staging':
    call_command("loaddata", "staging_fixture.json")
```

Comment: Great answer! How do you handle fixtures going out of date: do you treat them just like you would migrations? So if your fixture-loading migration is #3, and after 10 migrations the fixture is out of date, then do you just add a new migration that loads a new fixture that becomes migration #14?

Comment: Fixtures are inherently moment-in-time snapshots. If your database changes from a migration, they most likely won't work any more anyways. So, I would say, yes, if you create a new migration and need fixtures dealing specifically with that migration, you should simply create a new fixture based on the current state of the DB.